# how to intrepret time zones in following format "CST-9:30CDT,M10.1.0,M4.1.0" to change it on linux systems?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, datetime, time, timezone

I have a linux system on which I want to change timezone values . I am getting input from another service, which is sending values in format below

> CST-9:30CDT,M10.1.0,M4.1.0

I looked up standard python libraries but could not find any methods to intrepret this and configure it on a linux box.

Comment: Have you looked at `dateutil`?

Comment: Are you asking how to set your Linux system to this time zone?  Or are you asking how to use this time zone in Python?  (The former would be off-topic for StackOverflow.)

Comment: @MattJohnson i want to get hold of python/linux util  to convert "CST-9:30CDT,M10.1.0,M4.1.0" this  to the actual timezone "Australia/Adelaide" .
This link suggests that it is actual timezone,but no utility exists to convert this.Unless I maintain a static map.
"http://famschmid.net/timezones.html"

Comment: You can't.  One cannot map a POSIX time zone to an IANA time zone.  You can *project* an IANA time zone to a POSIX time zone for a particular point in time, but it's not a perfect mapping.  POSIX time zones are only representative of a single set of transitions.  Also, your string is incorrect, as it's missing the `/3` at the end that would be needed to map to today's representation of when DST ends in south Australia.

Comment: Why can't the other service give you `Australia/Adelaide` in the first place?  What is it you are actually trying to achieve with what you're currently getting?  Note: a static map is a bad idea.  You will have to update it frequently.  (Indeed, the link you gave says as much at the top, but they haven't updated it in 5 years and their values weren't all that accurate or complete in 2012 either.)

Comment: BTW - some detail on POSIX time zones towards the bottom of [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).